# Вывод из базы данных php, mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Подскажите как правильно написать, есть вывод записей из базы, это посты которые выводятся в ленте от друзей, и только
вот так:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tb1.user_id, tb1.friend_id
    , tb2.id, tb2.user_id, tb2.wall_id, tb2.repost_id
    , tb2.text, tb2.photos, tb2.video, tb2.audio, tb2.type
    , tb2.time, tb2.clike, tb2.ulike, tb2.crepost, tb2.urepost, tb2.comm 
  FROM `friends` tb1,`wall` tb2 
  WHERE tb1.user_id = '".$user_id."' 
    AND tb1.friend_id = tb2.user_id 
    AND tb2.wall_id = tb2.user_id 
  ORDER by tb2.time DESC 
  LIMIT $start,100");
```

Нужно чтоб также выводило и мои посты, так как так выводит только от друзей, как правильно написать?

Comment: Ну как-то можно) Какой вопрос, такой ответ. Приведите хотя бы схематично структуру Вашей базы данных, бизнес-логику. Пока по конкретному запросу сказать что-то очень сложно. Это просто запрос, он не отражает ничего.

Comment: Ну так выводятся записи из базы, посты, вывод идет только от тех кто у меня в друзьях, собственно надо чтоб там же выводило мои записи и записи от друзей, не понимаю как правильно написать(
while ($arr = $res->fetch_array()) echo wall_post($arr);

Comment: @Хаотик структуру бд (таблиц с постами) в студию

Comment: `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `wall_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `photos` text,
  `video` text,
  `audio` text,
  `ulike` text,
  `clike` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `urepost` text,
  `crepost` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `comm` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `repost_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL

Comment: @Хаотик Уже лучше, но чего-то не хватает. В какую таблицу ваши записи попадают ? в эту же (friends) ? или wall ? или иное ?

Comment: записи идут в wall, friends там для того чтобы выводило записи только от тех людей которые у меня там в друзьях в friends, а надо чтоб выводило так и плюс и мои выводило но мои не выводит

Comment: @Хаотик ну у вас же в wall 100% есть колонка с id пользователя. Свой id вы где-то да храните. Пусть в сессионной переменной. Вот и подставьте его в запрос. Типа wall.поле_с_айди_того_кто_публиковал = мой_айди

Comment: Вот так?
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tb1.user_id, tb1.friend_id, tb2.id, tb2.user_id, tb2.wall_id, tb2.repost_id, tb2.text, tb2.photos, tb2.video, tb2.audio, tb2.type, tb2.time, tb2.clike, tb2.ulike, tb2.crepost, tb2.urepost, tb2.comm FROM `friends` tb1,`wall` tb2 WHERE tb1.user_id = '".$user_id."' AND tb2.wall_id = '".$user_id."' AND tb1.friend_id = tb2.user_id AND tb2.wall_id = tb2.user_id ORDER by tb2.time DESC LIMIT $start,100");

Не работает(

Comment: почему не срабатывает если добавить AND tb2.wall_id = '".$user_id."' ?, wall_id от чьей стены, и user_id мой ид